# jquery-ui-datetimepicker-addon returned value always has time set to 00:00

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-datepicker, datetimepicker

I am calling `$("#from_date").datetimepicker("getDate")` and no matter what the hours/minutes scrollers are set to, the returned value has its time part set to 0.

What am I doing wrong / missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I modified the script like this:

```
            //if (date && tp_inst._parseTime($(target).val(), tp_inst.timeOnly))
        try
        {
            date.setHours(tp_inst.hour, tp_inst.minute, tp_inst.second, tp_inst.millisec);
        }
        catch (err)
        {
            window.console && console.log(err)
        }
```

I didn't investigate in depth but I think the problem is, that I use an altField and the parsed $(target).val() is the date instead of the time. I also tried with the time but the parser didn't handle it. So I just add the values to the date and this works for me.